# when I try to get li elements inside a ul I only get one li and nothing else

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to build a data extract for my company and I need to get the data inside a html list but when I execute my code I only get the text of a single `li` element below I shared my code.

screenshots of the site source and my result.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()

driver.get("http://turkosb.com/kaynarca-mobilya-ihtisas-organize-sanayi-bolgesi.html")


results = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='firma-info']/li")
print(results.text)
```

[image: Heres the site and the list data I want to extract]

But despite my efforts the result I get is the same I only get the text from first li element like this:

```
YETKİLİ KİŞİ: Fikret ARSLAN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `driver.find_element_by_xpath` is returning first element. It may highlight to all the `li` in the DOM, but you are asking to find a single element and it returns the first one.

Use `find_elements` to find all the `li` tags and iterate to get the text from them.

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='firma-info']/li")
for result in results:
     print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` is to fetch the only single web element. where as `find_elements` is to **get list of web elements.**

**so instead of**

```
results = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='firma-info']/li")
```

**try this :**

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='firma-info']/li")
```

Now results with `find_elements` is a list. **Iterate** it like this :

```
for res in results:
    print(res.text)
```